# PostGIS Raster layers not rendering in QGIS 3.14

Tags: qgis, postgis, raster, qgis-3

I am having an issue with the rendering of PostGIS raster layers using QGIS 3.14

I have a PostGIS DB with multiple rasters and on QGIS 3.10 these are displaying as they should.

When trying to open the raster I am getting that the raster has loaded, as it appears in the Layers panel correctly, but it is not visible within my workspace, it just doesn't render on the screen

Is there anyway to correct this, has a setting been changed regarding this, or is this a regression when using PostGIS raster layers with QGIS 3.14

Im running[image] Im running PostGRES 9.6 with QGIS 3.14.16 on Windows 10

Comment: Just to make sure, did you add it using DB management tool? or you added directly from browser?

Comment: I have tried both ways but it is not rendering as it was in QGIS 3.10. Just showing up in the layers panel but not displaying.