# PostGIS raster not loading in QGIS (version >3.10 on MacOS and Windows)

Tags: qgis, raster, postgis, qgis-3, rasterio

When loading PostGIS rasters (through the brower or via DBmanager) from my database into QGIS (LTR versions on both MacOS (Big Sur) and Windows 10), these fail to render. Either nothing shows up, or a band is shown covering most of the UTM zone in which the raster is positioned (see image below. In this case, the original raster covers less than a square kilometer).

In QGIS 3.10 everything works perfectly. In QGIS versions after that, despite the rasters being listed in the layers' panel, nothing is being visualised (or I get the odd error below).

I noticed a [couple](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374660/postgis-raster-layers-not-rendering-in-qgis-3-14) of [posts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/390477/postgis-rasters-now-loading-differently-with-qgis-3-14) have mentioned similar issues, but without any response. I'll file an issue in the QGis issue queue, and will update here when I can.

[image: example of erroneous PostGIS raster visualisation in QGIS 3.14 (MacOS)]

Comment: It is better to submit this kind of problems at [QGIS Issue](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS) queue. Please add your version of PostgreSQL, PostGIS and GDAL. If you can share one of your rasters there, even better. PostGIS rasters are working well on QGIS.

Comment: Thanks - I'll follow your advice and do that. Will update here when resolved.